# Rcpp and parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rcpp

I have an Rcpp routine that is given an R function and then does various computations. When run as such it works just fine. Now I want to run it in parallel, and then I get the error

*Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)): 4 nodes produced errors; first error: NULL value passed as symbol address*

A toy example is here. The routine is supposed to generate 10 observations from a normal distribution with the mean passed as an argument:

The Rcpp code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector tst(Function f, double m) {
   NumericVector out=f(m);
   return out;
}
```

and running

```
f=function(m) {rnorm(10, m)}
tst(f, 5)
```

works fine. But trying

```
cl <- makeCluster(4)
z=clusterCall(cl, tst, f, 5)
```

results in the error.

In the real routine f could be any routine that generates data, even something not part of base R.

Wolfgang

Comment: the general advice is to wrap your Rcpp code in a package :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074310/using-rcpp-within-parallel-code-via-snow-to-make-a-cluster ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518387/using-rcpp-functions-inside-of-rs-parapply-functions-from-the-parallel-package ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56225145/how-to-parallelise-c-code-when-using-rcpp

Comment: And that advice has been give here a few dozen times. Alternative, you can call `sourceCpp()` or `cppFunction()` on each node.  A function you build that is _local_ to the session, however a package can be loaded everwhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had read many of the discussions on the subject before, and even created a package, but kept getting error messages. I have it running now, even though I am not sure what the problem was before.

Anyway, thanks for the replies!

Comment: Glad you have it working but that sounds too non-deterministic for computers :)  I had this covered in some of the old 'HPC with R' tutorials so there are stanzas should you need it.